# How do i add disable a checkbox using php

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM seats WHERE SeatStatus = 1";
$display = @mysql_query($query);


if ($display){
$disable = "disable";
}


    <input name="ch1" type="checkbox" id="A1" value="" <?php echo $disable ?>/>;
```

how do i add "disable" inside the code...ive tried many time..but still didnt work..
Im new with php btw...Thanks..~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you are not checking if the query returned any results or an empty set. You are just checking whether the query is successful. `mysql_query()` would return false only when the query is wrong. In your case the query is correct, so `$display = mysql_query();` will always evaluate to a non-false value.

To solve this, you should check how many rows `mysql_query()` returns using `mysql_num_rows()`.  So let's rewrite your code.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM seats WHERE SeatStatus = 1";
$result = @mysql_query($query);
$display = (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1);

$disable = $display?'':'disabled="disabled"';

   <input name="ch1" type="checkbox" id="A1" value="" <?php echo $disable; ?>/>;
```

Hope that helps...

Peace...

Comment: I forgot to put the "d" at the end of the code...the thing is i wan to make my checkbox to be disabled if seatStatus is true, else nothing happen..do you know the codes?

Comment: Seat_ID 1 | 2 | 3 || SeatStatus 0 | 0 | 0....So if i click checkBox and hit reserve...it should be automatically change the SeatStatus to 1[worked] and the checkbox to be disable[still not working]...

Comment: edit your question and give more details and codes about your problem for a better solution.

Comment: @ahmedtabrez This method WORKS ! Thank BRO ! Ive been solving this for weeks... THANK YOU VERY MUCH...YOU MAKE ME CRY T_T..~ LOL

Comment: Its my email name btw since saiful was taken..and its my first time here...never explore anything yet...~ btw thank you so much !

Answer (score 1):

The attribute value is [`disabled`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-disabled) not `disable`, just add a `d`.

Comment: oh ya thx btw...its worked..but the thing is i wan to make its

if the SeatStatus value is 1 it will disabled the checkbox else nothing happen...

this code wrong?

Comment: Forms only submit successful controls. A checkbox is only a successful control if it is checked and is not disabled.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" <?php echo ($condition) ? ' disabled="disabled"' : '';/>
```

Comment: how do i use this...is it

<input type="checkbox" <?php echo ($display) ?> 'disabled' : '';/>

Comment: @Ahmad : No that's a ternary if

Answer (score 0):

What you actually want is not clear for me. I think you want to find all seats where its status equals to 1. if seats are available(status = 1) disable checkbox.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM seats WHERE SeatStatus = 1";
$result = @mysql_query($query);

$num_rows = @mysql_num_rows($result);

$disable = '';
if (!$num_rows){
$disable = 'disabled="disabled"';
}

<input name="ch1" type="checkbox" id="A1" value="" <?php echo $disable ?>/>;
```

Comment: i have tried it and still failed. am i missing something?

$query = "SELECT count(*) FROM seats WHERE SeatStatus = 1";
$display = @mysql_query($query)

$disable = '';
if (!$display){
$disable = 'disabled="disabled"';
}

<input name="ch1" type="checkbox" id="A1" value="" <?php echo $disable ?>/>;

Comment: at the input end did you put the name you want to display? `<input name="ch1" type="checkbox" id="A1" value="" <?php echo $disable ?>/> Display`

Comment: i did not put display...if i use the top method...it will disabled the checkbox straight away...that the problem..

Comment: when the page is load your checking there are seats where status=1( there can be many seats rite). if there are seats (`$display>0`) available then you want to disable the checkbox. if not which means (`$display=0`) you want to enable checkbox. am I rite? the code should work if this is the requirement you want. try a echo the `$display` value and see the SQL query is working correctly.

Comment: yeah this is exactly what i want...i echo the $display...it display Resources #4...what is that mean?

Comment: use var_dump($display) it will give you information. echo and print_r() might not work with the way you execute query.

Answer (score 0):

Replace`disable` with `disabled`